# ListView with CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE. Select up to one choice

Tags: android, listview

I have a multi choice list inside an AlertDialog.

Reading the documentation of CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, I thought that you could have one or **no** item checked but for me it behaves like a Radio Button List. It starts with all checkboxes unchecked by default by once I check one, it cannot be unchecked.

I tried hacking it with manual setItemChecked inside onClick but that is not a solution.

What am I doing wrong? How to achieve one or no checkbox in a ListView?

Here's my code:

```
       builder.setMultiChoiceItems(titles,  new boolean[titles.length], new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean b) {
                if (selectedId == -1) {
                    selectedId = position;
                } else {
                    if (selectedId == position) {
                        mDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(position, false);
                        selectedId = -1;
                    } else {
                        mDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(selectedId, false);
                        selectedId = position;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mDialog = builder.create();
        mDialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code isn't working because the method that you are using, setItemChecked, doesn't change the selected state when receive a false and is working on CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, which is the normal behaviour of a group of radio buttons. You can see it by yourself with "Go To Implementation" in Android Studio (Ctrl + RightClick over the method).

Also, it's not recommended to use checkboxes for a single choice selector as it will confuse your users. You can easily get radio buttons replacing setMultipleChoiceItems by setSingleChoiceItems. It also apply the single choice mode to your ListView, so you can get rid of your last line.

To allow the user to perform an empty selection with radio buttons you have mainly 2 options:

- Add an extra items to your list representing the empty selection option. Label it as "None", "Uncheck" or something similar
- Add an extra button to your dialog to dismiss the dialog and return an empty selection.

Here you have a sample of implementation of the first option adding dynamically the empty item for a better re-usability ;)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBKSD.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String title = "Select your favourite language";
    String[] items = {"English", "Spanish", "Chinese", "Java"};
    String emptyItemTitle = "NONE OF THEM";
    int initialSelection = 0;

    showSingleChoiceDialogWithNoneOption(title, items, initialSelection, emptyItemTitle);
}

private void showSingleChoiceDialogWithNoneOption(String title, final String[] titleItems, int initialSelection, String emptyItemTitle ) {

    final String[] extendedItems = addEmptyItem(titleItems, emptyItemTitle);
    final int[] selectedPosition = {initialSelection};

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(extendedItems, initialSelection, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    selectedPosition[0] = which;
                    Log.d("MyTag", String.format("Selected item '%s' at position %s.", extendedItems[which], which));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("MyTag", String.format("Confirmed the selection of '%s' at position %s.", extendedItems[selectedPosition[0]], selectedPosition[0]));
                    onSelectionConfirmed(selectedPosition[0]);
                }
            })
            .show();
}

@NonNull
private String[] addEmptyItem(String[] titleItems, String emptyTitle) {
    String[] tempArray = new String[titleItems.length + 1];
    tempArray[0] = emptyTitle;
    System.arraycopy(titleItems, 0, tempArray, 1, titleItems.length);
    return tempArray;
}

private void onSelectionConfirmed(int position) {
    if (position==0){
        //Handle your empty selection
    }else{
        //Selected item at position 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the alternative but it's not what I'm looking for. CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE states "up to one choice" and that's what I want to achieve in a checkbox list without adding another option for "none".

Comment: Let me insist you, according to UI/UX global principles for all platforms: checkbox is for multiple choices and radio buttons for single choice.

Comment: What do you think about the second option without an extra item in the list? (Adding an extra button to your dialog to dismiss the dialog and return an empty selection) Then you could have at the bottom of your dialog the following buttoms: Cancel, None and OK.

Comment: For my use case, a list of checkboxes with the behavior described in CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE (one or no option) would be best without cluttering it with extra choices or buttons. I still didn't get if there's a bug in CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or my understanding of it is wrong because its initial state is with all checkboxes unchecked.

Comment: Its not a bug, is the normal behaviour for single choice selections: initially unselected but preventing clear selection once something has been selected.

Without any button or extra item you can try to modify the components created by the DialogBuilder, but they can have different implementations on older versions. In Android 7 there are AppCompatCheckedTextView but probably it use a different component for older APIs.

Comment: Also there are a more flexible approach that could fit better your needs as you don't want a standard behaviour: using your own customLayout in the body of your DialogBuilder. In this way you define the xml and the logic, so you have the full control over the list, his adapter and the selection components, allowing you to implement their behaviour as you wish (even with checkboxes ':)

Comment: I'm kind of stuck on the adapter part. As in toggling different rows than the one currently clicked to achieve the none or one checkbox behavior.

Comment: If you have a fix number of items, you could skip the adapter part and compose a static layout with all your checkboxes and labels, but a dynamic solution is always better. Share your current code and I will try to assist you.

Comment: In the end I used a radio button group and a row for the invalid value. Thanks!